# How can I use Storefront SCSS Variables in the Administration?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, shopware

In the Storefront of Shopware 6 Themes and Plugins you can define SCSS Variables to facilitate your development. Now I also want to use these Variables in the Administration, especially when I want to implement new Vue Components. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which kind of variables are you talking about? Do you want to influence the style of the admin by the frontend colors and so on? As Skoenig said, it's not clear which store front to use, as there are multiple ones. Or are you talking about the CMS editor and want some kind of frontend preview?

Answer (score 1):

Theoraticly you can load them via API call. But since you've multiple saleschannels or themes, it's may difficult to decide which data you want to load.